# How to retrieve image from mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have stored image into mysql using following and now i want to retrieve... I want to convert ny image from bytes to image and then display it ... how can i do that

```
public void LoadImages()
        {
        byte[] ImageData;
        string image = txtLogo.Text;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        ImageData = BitConverter.GetBytes(fs.Length);                                    
        string query = "insert into Fn_Pictures(Images,Email)values(@Images,'" + txtEmailId.Text + "')";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader myReaeder;
        con.Open();
        myReaeder = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a complete overhead to store images in a database.
Just save them on the disk, it's a lot faster.

If you want to store them use blob, and you will need a different page for the image, with the right headers to display it.

Comment: faster how? faster why?

Comment: Hey @Strawberry can u give me solution for my ans

Comment: Faster because:
You cannot just select the image and print it in your page.
Your web server will allso do some caching on the image, so will the browser(the 2th visit usualy the image isn't redownloaded = saves a lot of traffic) only because of this i woudn't store it.

Allso you are making your rows a lot bigger = slower database

Answer (score 0):

In order to store images , store on disk

All you has to do is save the image path in Database or just image name and through dynamic coding you can retrieve absolute path of image , This would be much more faster , irespective of any technology

Comment: Sorry lampdev i have been using C#

Comment: This can be irrespective of any programming language